# Simple Maths with jQuery - division

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, division

I've got two inputs in a div that I want to divide one by the other.

```
<div>

<input type="number" id="a"> / <input type="number" id="b">

<input type="submit">

<p class="result">RESULT HERE</p> 

</div>
```

How can the maths of this be done with jquery?

Comment: What's the `label` attribute?

Comment: `label` isn't a real attribute.  I think you mean `id` or `name`.

Comment: The math can't be done with jQuery. You have to use simple JavaScript. I suggest you read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It really depends when you want the calculation to take place, but the maths itself is incredibly simple. Just use the standard [division operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators), `/`:

```
var num1 = $("input[label='a']").val(),
    num2 = $("input[label='b']").val(),
    result = parseInt(num1, 10) / parseInt(num2, 10);
$(".result").text(result);
```

I guess it also depends if you only want to support integer division (that's why I've used `parseInt` - you could use `parseFloat` if necessary).

Also, as mentioned in the comments on your question, `label` is not a valid attribute. A better option would be to use `id`, or if you need to use an arbitrarily named attribute, use HTML5 [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attributes.

**Update** based on comments

As you have stated that you want the code to run when a button is clicked, all you need to do is bind to the `click` event:

```
$("#someButton").click(function() {
    //Do stuff when the button is clicked.
});
```

Comment: thanks for this :) I'd want the user to be able to enter the two figures then click a submit button that'd then show the answer (on the same page if possible). I guess I need to add a submit button to my HTML ? :)

Comment: Yeah that's right, and you'd need to bind a click event handler to that element. See my edit.

Comment: `/` will automatically coerce into a number, so you could simply do `num1 / num2`.

Comment: @pimvdb - Yeah true, but I just wanted to make it clear what's actually going on, instead of letting the JS engine take care of it :)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing your markup with your logic. You can't divide HTML elements with each other they are for structural presentation only. Instead, you have to pull their values with javascript, apply the math, and update the HTML with the resulting value.